# mysql query not working gives and error

Tags: php, mysql

Hello guys i have two almost same querys but one is working and one not 
this one is working fine :

```
<?php 
require 'mysql.php';

if(isset($_POST["email"])){
    $email = $_POST["email"];

    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email=? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $rowcount = $result->num_rows;
            if ($rowcount > 0){
                echo "1";
            } else if($rowcount == 0){ 
                echo "0";
            }

}
?>
```

and this one is not working and gives me an error

> " Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object
>   in line 8 "

```
<?php
session_start();
require 'mysql.php';

    $userid = $_SESSION["userid"];

    $stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM character WHERE userid=? ");
    $stmt->bind_param("i", $userid); // line 8
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    $rowcount = $result->num_rows;
        if ($rowcount > 0){
            echo "1";
        }else{
            echo "0";
        }


?>
```

they are almost same only first one checks email and this one checks userid but second one are not working and first one are working fine where is the problem ???

Comment: that answer change nothing , and i was using ? all the time was working fine for me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `character` is [**reserved kerword**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html) in mysql it must be in backtick  query fails due to this and you got error

```
$stmt = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM `character` WHERE userid=? ");
```

Comment: tnx u sir works fine now